# Coloring x-axis labels for split barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. I'm trying to make a split barplot with different colors for the x-axis labels. I want the x-axis labels (e.g. Vogesella) to show up as the correct color when they are plotted on the graph according to the host species.
2. As you can see, none of the Vogesella x-axis labels are correct, and they are defaulting to black. I tried using vectorized input to element_text, but I get a warning saying that it isn't officially supported. Is there some workaround I can do to make this possible?
3. Here is the code that I used to make the simplified barplot.

System Info:
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin15.6.0
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0
status
major          3
minor          6.3
year           2020
month          02
day            29
svn rev        77875
language       R
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock

```
 df %>%
      ggplot( aes(x = genus, y = avg_rel_abund, fill = host_species))+
      geom_bar(stat = "Identity") +
      facet_grid(cols = vars(host_species), scales = "free") +
      scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 1) +
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, hjust = 1, size = 10, 
      color = df$color),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10)) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(size = 10)) +
      labs( y = "Relative Abundance (Genus)", title = "Day 3 Genera 
      Present in Host Phycospheres", fill = "Host Species") +
      scale_y_continuous("Average Relative Abundance") +
      scale_x_reordered()
```

Dataset:

```
    df <- structure(list(genus = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Vogesella___Coelastrum", 
    "Vogesella___Scenedesmus", "Vogesella___Chlorella", "Vogesella___Monoraphidium", 
    "Vogesella___Selenastrum"), class = "factor"), host_species = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Chlorella", "Coelastrum", "Scenedesmus", 
    "Monoraphidium", "Selenastrum"), class = "factor"), avg_rel_abund = c(0.0476201763676562, 
    0.0723617033127999, 0.0254124767307784, 0.0615452700310325, 0.0124210779718639
    ), time = c("D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3"), color = c("#7FC97F", 
    "#BEAED4", "black", "#FDC086", "#386CB0")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: Simplified Barplot]

[image: Simplified dataframe]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values, in your case `agg_genus_data_D3_color` or use dput(agg_genus_data_D3_color). These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: I'm a tad confused here. Should I add the output of dput(agg_genus_data_D3_color) to my question?

Comment: Yes, this will make your question reproducible so that potential answers can be tested and verified.

Comment: To be honest you would be better off making a much simpler toy dataset to illustrate your problem which seems to be colouring the x axes labels the same colours as your bars. If I understand you correctly. All the other information in your graph, is just distracting clutter to addressing the question, hence the request for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I apologize for the length of the dataset. I used droplevels() to make it shorter. If it needs to be smaller I can try subsetting or something. Alright give me a moment to shorten it

Comment: That would be enormously helpful.

Comment: Okay, hopefully the dataset I posted is a bit more helpful.

Comment: `agg_genus_data_D3_color$color` seems to be missing. Check if the question is missing by opening a new r file, copy the question data and code and see if it runs. You could also use the `reprex` package. Here's a link which could be useful viewing at some time: https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5

Comment: Sorry, I fully forgot to change that to df$color. I'll do those steps and then get back to you

Comment: I don't understand where this error is coming from with reprex(). Are we going in circles? Did you just run reprex()?
In that case, the clipboard now holds the *rendered* result.
Carry on with this reprex?
1: yes
2: no

Selection: yes
Rendering reprex...
Error: callr subprocess failed: attempt to use zero-length variable name

Comment: Probably best to leave `reprex` for another day. It is very rigorous if there is the slightest thing amiss with your code or data, including missing packages reprex throws an error. once you run reprex, all your data, code and outputs from your minimal reproducible script are on the clipboard, then you simply paste that into the SO question.

Comment: But back to your real question. An aside, you seem to be trying to include two y axis titles. More to the point, are you fixed on using `facet_grid`? as I think this is where your problem lies as each facet is using the first element of your colour vector hence they are all appearing the same colour. I think you need to revert to a simple `geom_col` or `geom_bar` approach if you want variable axis text colours.

Comment: Because of the sheer volume of the data I need to represent, and because x-axis titles vary between the host species groups, facet_grid lets me display the data in different frames. I also tried removing facet_grid and the axis titles still turn out wrong. Unless I could generate separate barplots and then combine using ggarrange or something.

Comment: See `geom_col` option in answer. I suspect your idea of combing plots is more likely to work unless someone comes up with a way to modify axis text colours in a facet. Have a look at `patchwork` and `cowplot` packages as other options for combining graphs.  Let me know if the answer does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it using `geom_col` rather than `facet_grid`. You can adjust the text at the head of the bars and or the plot size to make the text fit.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(df, aes(x = fct_inorder(genus, host_species), y = avg_rel_abund, fill = host_species))+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = host_species, y = Inf), vjust = 1, size = 3)+
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 1) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, hjust = 1, size = 10, 
                                   colour = df$color),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(size = 10)) +
  labs(y = "Average Relative Abundance",
       title = "Day 3 Genera\nPresent in Host Phycospheres",
       fill = "Host Species")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>